# sudo: port :command not found

Tags: macos, port

I have a macbook air. Have Python 2.7.5

Tried this in terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/opt/local/share/man
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/opt/local/share/info
```

But in vain. Still shows the same error.

Comment: ...and `ls -l /opt/local/bin/port` gives...?

Comment: ls: /opt/local/bin/port: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you sure you [installed macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php) correctly?